# Biblatex: capitalize first word with \citetitle

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I would like to capitalize the first word of the title in-text with the `\citetitle` macro, or at least being able to use the title of a reference with its first letter capitalized.

In the bibliographic entry, the first word of the title is lowercase so it can be cited lowercase when needed in the text.
Hence I redefined `titlecase` with the help of `\MakeSentenceCase` so the bibliography entry is correctly printed in the references section. If needed, words are protected by braces (see: `biblatex` manual, `MakeSentenceCase` definition).

I tried `\Citetitle` without success, but I am not sure to understand what it really does.

My goal is to be able to deal with capitalization of titles in french when they start a sentence (see: [J.-P. Lacroux, Orthotypographie vol. II](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/telegramme-troncation.html#Titre-d_oeuvre)), but I deliberately simplified the question.

MWE, to be produced with `(pdf)latex file.tex ; biber file ; (pdf)latex file.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@book{
mybook,
title=  {title of the book},
author= {Author Name},
date=   {2021-04-12},
}

@article{
myarticle,
title=  {title of the article},
author= {Author Name},
date=   {2021-04-12},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\citetitle{mybook} ; \Citetitle{mybook}

\citetitle{myarticle} ; \Citetitle{myarticle}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `titlecase` field format does not apply to `\citetitle`. We can make it apply to `citetitle` with the following redefinition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[citetitle]{%
     \printfield[titlecase]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
  title  = {title of the book},
  author = {Author Name},
  date   = {2021-04-12},
}
@article{myarticle,
  title  = {title of the article},
  author = {Author Name},
  date   = {2021-04-12},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citetitle{mybook}

\Citetitle{mybook}

\citetitle{myarticle}

\Citetitle{myarticle}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Title of the book//Title of the book//“Title of the article”//“Title of the article”]

---

If you only want to capitalise the first word with `\Citetitle` things are a bit more tricky. In that case I'd recommend the following, which is based on `\MakeCapital` and not on `\MakeSentenceCase`, which means it does not alter subsequent letters and does not respond to language settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[citetitle]{%
     \printfield[ifcap]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{ifcap}{\ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
  title  = {title of the book},
  author = {Author Name},
  date   = {2021-04-12},
}
@article{myarticle,
  title  = {title of the article},
  author = {Author Name},
  date   = {2021-04-12},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citetitle{mybook}

\Citetitle{mybook}

\citetitle{myarticle}

\Citetitle{myarticle}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: title of the Book//Title of the Book//“title of the Article”//“Title of the Article”]